# Converting SQL DB to .sql

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, desktop-application

I'm developing a project in C# which I use a internal SQL DB, however the DB modified within my program can be used aswell for an online aplication because is the same table structure and data, so I want to add a button to my c# app in which I'm able to "udpate" the online app that uses mysql DB.

So basically I want to convert the internal SQL DB to an output file extension .sql so I can manually upload it to mysql, or... a function that connects to mysql and makes a "mirror".

Thanks! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For exporting structure and data to external databases, you can use the standard SQL Server Integration Services. [Here is a good tutorial](http://dbperf.wordpress.com/2010/07/23/sql-server-integration-services-2008-ssis-and-mysql/) on exactly how to do this.

However, if you have the budget for it, I would strongly recommend one of the [Red-Gate](http://www.red-gate.com/) tools, probably [Sql Packager](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-packager/) and/or [Sql Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/). These tools are generally used between Sql Server databases, but Sql Packager does an excellent job of creating an output script and, if you keep another Sql Server database that mimics your MySql database, you can use Sql Data Compare to generate a script that can be used to synchronize the data.